Why is a struct with two booleans 8 bytes when laid out with `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)`?
This is my struct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SystemServiceStatus {
        public bool isSystemUiOverlaid;
        public bool isInBackgroundExecution;
    }

When setting both booleans to true, I get the following in binary (hex):
01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
I don't know if this is because of padding... or if my booleans are serialized as 32-bit ints and laid out with little endian.
ChatGPT seems very confident that the two booleans should have been side by side in the first two bytes, but that's obviously not right.

See this post: What is the size of a boolean In C#? Does it really take 4-bytes?.

I found my answer.
C# StructLayout Pack=?? for use with bool values
TLDR; The default way to treat bools is as ints, but it can be controlled by putting a [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] on each bool, to force it to be one byte.
